# Gatilho Onchange em select - javascript

Tags: javascript, html-select

Olá, tenho um projeto, e preciso que, ao selecionar determinado item em um select, apareça(ou não) outros itens, me parece bem simples, mas me surpreendi pela dificuldade que estou tendo ao fazê-lo, eis o que tenho testado até o momento:

```
Selecione um carro da lista<br>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select><br><br>

<div id="modelo" style="display:none;">Escolha um modelo<br><select>
<option value="x1">x1</option>
<option value="x2">x2</option>
<option value="x3">x3</option>
<option value="x4">x4</option>
</select></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
if x.value == ("BMW"){
    document.getElementById("modelo").style.display = 'block'; 
}
}
</script>
```

Basicamente, ele deveria, quando selecionada a marca `BMW`, mudar o status do estilo display da div modelo, mas não funciona.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem alguns erros bem simples de resolver no teu código.

Você está atribuindo o valor do select diretamente na tua `var x`

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
```

No if onde você verifica se é BMW, estão faltando os parenteses

```
if x.value == ("BMW")
```

Como resolver?

Você pode corrigir somente no if, da seguinte maneira

```
if (x === 'BMW')
```

Mas se você for usar o elemento em outros locais futuramente, atribua apenas o elemento na `var x` e no if apenas adicione os parenteses.

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
if (x.value === 'BMW') {
    document.getElementById("modelo").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Aproveitando o código do @Brunno, você pode adicionar o evento diretamente no javascript ao invés de por no on-change do select.

```
var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
select.addEventListener('change', myFunction);
```

Comment: +1 e Segue um [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/bjzvb6Lz/) para complementar =]